# Loading a Postgres view using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis, spatial-view

Under QGIS 1.8 on Windows 7 I have this problem with my pyArchInit plugin: I need to load on the map canvas my geometries from a PostGIS layer. Till the 1.7.4 version I use the method explained on the tutorial.

But I have to load also some Potgres view, and QGIS 1.8 need to know the column that I would like to use as ID.

How can I pass this value with PyQGIS and restore my plugin?

```
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
# set host name, port, database name, username and password
uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "dbname", "johny", "xxx")
# set database schema, table name, geometry column and optionaly subset (WHERE clause)
uri.setDataSource("public", "roads", "the_geom", "cityid = 2643")

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "layer_name_you_like", "postgres")
```

Answer (score 6):

[QgsDataSourceURI.setDataSource()](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsDataSourceURI.html#aedf47ddf31b03af376a5c35ca2b17a54) has an additional fifth argument to specify the key column.

Answer (score 2):

An update and an explicit example to complete @jef's answer :

```
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "myDatabase", "myUser", "myPassword")
uri.setDataSource("mySchema", "myTable", "myGeomField", aKeyColumn="myUniqueIdField")
vlayer = iface.addVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), "nameOfMyLayer", "postgres")
```

Adapt it with your database settings.

[Source](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Data/QgsDataSourceUri.html?highlight=setdatasource#module-QgsDataSourceUri)