# Getting active PostgreSQL connection username when stored through authentication configuration in QGIS 3.16

Tags: qgis, postgis

How do I get the username on the current layer PostGIS in QGIS 3.16.2-Hannover?
We tried examples: [Getting active PostgreSQL connection username when stored through authentication configuration in QGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/318635/getting-active-postgresql-connection-username-when-stored-through-authentication), but they don't work.

When running this script, variable `username` is empty:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
provider = layer.dataProvider()
username = QgsDataSourceUri(provider.dataSourceUri()).username()
print (username)
```

This is result of `provider.dataSourceUri())`:

> <QgsDataSourceUri: dbname='postgres' host= localhost port=5432
> sslmode=disable key='id' srid=4326 type=Point
> checkPrimaryKeyUnicity='1' table="locations"."airlines" (geom)>

The value of the username is missing, the question is how to get the username for the current layer?

Comment: What does "they don't work" mean?

Comment: I have tried it as well. I got also username is empty but the reason (in my case) I am connected with local credentials so there is no user and psw. Can you check if you see the 'user' when you print out `provider.dataSourceUri()`?

Comment: I don't understand: you are referring to a question that gives you the solution, doesn't it ?

Comment: the solution to the question I am referring to does not answer my question.
Function - QgsDataSourceUri(provider.dataSourceUri()).username() return empty string

Comment: @AndreySirbu what does it return if you call only provider.dataSourceUri()??

Comment: This is result of provider.dataSourceUri()):
<QgsDataSourceUri: dbname='postgres' host= localhost port=5432 sslmode=disable key='id' srid=4326 type=Point checkPrimaryKeyUnicity='1' table="locations"."airlines" (geom)>

Comment: As you see, you do not have any username or password there. That's the reason why your username returns empty. This is the result of provider.dataSourceUri() for me `'dbname=\'postgres\' host=localhost port=5432 user=\'postgres\' password=\'postgres\' key=\'id\' checkPrimaryKeyUnicity=\'1\' table="public"."items" sql='` and QgsDataSourceUri(provider.dataSourceUri()).username() returns postgres

Comment: Ok, then how can I get the username, because when opening a layer from postgres, QGIS prompts me to enter the username and password ? 

I think that when you opened the layer, you specified store username and password in the Edit PostGis Connection dialog option, but this approach does not suit, if the user does not specify the store (username and password) option, then the function will not work. How to get username in all cases without store option?

Comment: I see. Maybe you can take a look at this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28743/how-to-load-a-postgres-view-using-pyqgis ?

Comment: the setConnection () function works, but the problem is when to call it because the user is opening the layers through the standard QGis interface - Layer->Add Layer->Add PostGis Layers... (Ctrl+Shift+D)?
Example:
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "postgres", "user1", "pwd")
uri.setDataSource("locations", "airlines", "geom", aKeyColumn="id")
vlayer = iface.addVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), "airlines", "postgres")

layer = iface.activeLayer()
provider = layer.dataProvider()
username = QgsDataSourceUri(provider.dataSourceUri()).username()
print (username)

Answer (score 0):

You can select your PostgreSQL user using the 'PostgreSQL Execute SQL' command in the Processing toolbox.

Query:

```
SELECT user;
```

[image]

Comment: how to get user name from script?

Comment: How to use python  function?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this have changed since version 3.16 but in 3.32 you can simply do:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
print(layer.source())
#dbname='data' host=localhost port=5432 user='postgres' 
#sslmode=disable key='id' estimatedmetadata=true srid=3006 
#type=MultiPolygon checkPrimaryKeyUnicity='1' table="lmv"."ok_ak_riks" (geom)
```